# Широковещательный запрос на ПК у другого провайдера

Tags: сеть, arp, провайдер, osi

Предположим, ПК провайдера 1 передает информацию на ПК провайдера 2. Как будет происходить определение MAC-адреса ПК провайдера 2? Знаю, что происходит широковещательный запрос на канальном уровне модели OSI, а как именно не понимаю..

P.S. Я в сетях начинающий, так что возможные противоречия, ошибки - ненамеренные

Comment: Тут два противоречие. Широковещательный пакет (запрос) отличается от обычного тем, что шлется просто всем, т.е. он не содержит МАС-адрес впринципе. Если такой пакет свич выпустит второму провайдеру - он удачно пройдет. Для передачи такого запроса МАС не нужен.

Comment: А второе противоречие - врядли два провайдера будут включены в одну звезду, обычный запрос передаётся до МАС-адреса назвачения, потом происходит смена МАС в пакете через АRP таблицу (т.е. важен IP а не МАС), и запрос шлётся дальше. Но для широковещательного будет по-другому, т.к. у него нету МАС.

Comment: ПК у провайдера 1 не будет получать MAC конечного устройства. Он заглянет в свою таблицу маршрутизации из которой узнает IP шлюза своего провайдера, через который отправлять пакет. Получит ARP запросом (широковещательным, в своем сегменте) MAC шлюза провайдера и пошлет пакет на него. На этом все. Дальше уже маршрутизатор провайдера точно так же выяснит по своей таблице маршрутизации куда слать пакет дальше. И так пакет дойдет до сети назначения. Там уже конечный маршрутизатор провайдера 2 получить ARP MAC назначения и отдаст ему пакет